# how can I pass elements in a vector to a function as parameters in R?

Tags: r

I would like to pass a vector as part of parameter of a function.

Here is the toy sample, please advise.

```
func <- function(a, b, c) {sum(a, b, c)}

func(1,2,3)
# [1] 6

# vector of parameters
x = c(1, 2)

func(x, 3)
# Error in func(x, 3) : argument "c" is missing, with no default

func(unlist(x), 3)
# Error in func(unlist(x), 3) : argument "c" is missing, with no default

func(x[1], x[2], 3)
# 6

mapply(func, c(x, 3)) # Not working
mapply(func, c(unlist(x), 3)) # Not working
mapply(func, unlist(x), 3) # Not working
mapply(func, x[1], x[2], 3) # Working but more complicated
```

Since the parameter vectot could be very long and complicated in real case, how can I make it easier?
Thanks for advice.

*UPDATE*

`do.call` way is working at plain case. At my real case, I am treating something like this.

```
library(keras)
imDim = c(150, 150)
input <- layer_input(shape = c(imDim[1], imDim[2], 3)
```

in `do.call` method, it shall become, `input <- do.call(layer_input, as.list(c(imDim,3))`. seems not less complicated.

Or in other case,

```
# toy example: a is an input layer 
Layer1 <- layer_conv_2d(filters = 32, kernel_size = c(3, 2), 
          activation = "relu", input_shape = c(150, 150, 3))

# what if the dimension of image may change, the flexibility shall be there.
Shape <- c(150, 150)

# to make the code readable, 
# I set a function to accept parameters coming from do.call.

LayerFunc <- function(p, q) {layer_conv_2d(filters = 32, 
             kernel_size = c(3, 2), activation = "relu", 
             input_shape = c(p, q, 3))}

# pass parameter with do.call 
Layer2 <- do.call(LayerFunc, as.list(c(Shape)))

# however Layer1 & Layer2 are different, 
# besides, the do.call way seems more complicated

identical(a, d)
#> Layer1
#<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D>
#> Layer2
#<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D>
#> identical(Layer1, Layer2)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

If you print the value of `a` you'll realise what is happening in the function.

```
func <- function(a, b, c) print(a)

func(1, 2, 3)
#[1] 1

x = c(1, 2)
func(x, 3)
#[1] 1 2
```

So in the second example both 1, 2 are considered as `a` and not `a` and `b` as you expected.

To overcome this one way would be to pass list of arguments to the function with the help of `do.call`.

```
do.call(func, as.list(c(x, 3)))
#[1] 1
```

Change to the original function.

```
func <- function(a, b, c) sum(a, b, c)
do.call(func, as.list(c(x, 3)))
#[1] 6
```

Comment: Many thanks. I have considered `do.call` method as you suggested, and of course it does work perfectly. Yet, it's more like `grab an apple at one time` rather than `project all the apples to where each of them should belong`. I mean, in `do.call` way, all parameters shall be well organized if each of elements is for different purposes.

Comment: Do you expect something else from the answer?

Comment: Please forgive if my poor english shall offend you. I mean there shall be ways to achieve same goal. I am just looking for suggestions, and thinking if there is way of `vectorized operation`, since I am not as experienced as you are.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide an example where this answer fails or maybe part of the answer that you want to change.

Comment: please find the updated. It might explain me better. Thanks.

Comment: @Grec001 Why are you passing 3 arguments to `LayerFunc`?  It only accepts 2 i.e `p` and `q`. `Shape` already has 2 then why pass additional 3 which you have already hardcoded as 3 in the function as `input_shape = c(p, q, 3)`

Comment: Thanks, my bad. It explains why they are different, yet it also indicate lengthy code could go wrong with sloppy coder as I am. LOL